# Add Markers to Leaflet Map

Tags: javascript, html, csv, leaflet, gis

I'm attempting to add data from a CSV file to a Leaflet map but the points taken from the file aren't populating on the map.
I'm using the code below to parse the CSV file and create markers from the entries.

```
var data = './data.csv';
    var lines = data.split("\n");
    var markers = [];
    for (var i=1; i<lines.length; i++) {
        var parts = lines[i].split(",");
        if (i>1) {
            markers.push( [parts[0], Number(parts[18]), Number(parts[19]) ]);
```

And this is the code I'm using to add the markers to the map.

```
for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
            var lat = markers[i][1];
            var lon = markers[i][2];
            var popupText = markers[i][0];
            
            var markerLocation = new L.LatLng(lat, lon);
            var marker = new L.Marker(markerLocation);
            map.addLayer(marker);
            
            marker.bindPopup(popupText);
```

Here is a sample taken from the CSV file, columns A, S, and T are the ones I'm attempting to get lat/long and popup information from.

[image]

Here is the full HTML file in case I'm missing something elsewhere in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI=" crossorigin="" />
  <title>PSS Leaflet Map</title>

  <style>
    body { margin:0; padding:0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top:20px; bottom:20px; right:0; left:0; }
  </style>

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Insert HTML division tag to layout the map -->
  <div id="map"></div>
  
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>

  <!-- Insert code to create the map -->
  <script>

    var Wilmington = new L.LatLng(34.2104, -77.8868);
    var map = L.map('map').setView(Wilmington, 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    <!-- create array from csv data -->
    var data = './data.csv';
    var lines = data.split("\n");
    var markers = [];
    for (var i=1; i<lines.length; i++) {
        var parts = lines[i].split(",");
        if (i>1) {
            markers.push( [parts[0], Number(parts[18]), Number(parts[19]) ]);
}}
    <!-- add data from array to map -->
    for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
            var lat = markers[i][1];
            var lon = markers[i][2];
            var popupText = markers[i][0];
            
            var markerLocation = new L.LatLng(lat, lon);
            var marker = new L.Marker(markerLocation);
            map.addLayer(marker);
            
            marker.bindPopup(popupText);
    }

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I open it in a browser, this is what I see. Does anyone have any ideas/advice on what I'm missing to get the markers to display on the map?

[image]

Comment: The official documentation suggests calling L.marker([50.5, 30.5]).addTo(map); Or in your case replace 'map.addLayer(marker);' with 'marker.addTo(map);'

Comment: From the posted code, it seems that you never read the CSV file. You do `var data = './data.csv';` where `data` is a string, then `var lines = data.split("\n");` resulting in `lines` equals `'./data.csv'` but not the file content.